# How solve mysql 5.7 dependency?

Tags: linux, mysql

tried to install Mysql server from repo
installed repo

```
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el7-8.noarch.rpm
 sudo rpm -ivh mysql57-community-release-el7-8.noarch.rpm
yum update
```

after

```
yum install mysql-community-server
```

returned error

```
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-libs-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
           Requires: libsasl2.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
           Requires: systemd
```

How to solve this problem?

OS version:

```
Linux dbmysql01 4.1.12-103.3.8.el6uek.x86_64 #2 SMP Mon Aug 21 17:27:50 PDT 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Tryied variant by Tomas

```
yum remove mysql57-community-release.noarch
yum install https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch.rpm
yum install mysql-community-server
```

returned result

```
Loaded plugins: security, ulninfo
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:5.7.19-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-common(x86-64) = 5.7.19-1.el7 for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-client(x86-64) >= 5.7.9 for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnuma.so.1(libnuma_1.2)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnuma.so.1(libnuma_1.1)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libaio.so.1(LIBAIO_0.4)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libaio.so.1(LIBAIO_0.1)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsasl2.so.3()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnuma.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libaio.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libaio.x86_64 0:0.3.107-10.el6 will be installed
---> Package mysql.x86_64 0:5.1.73-8.0.1.el6_8 will be obsoleted
---> Package mysql-community-client.x86_64 0:5.7.19-1.el7 will be obsoleting
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-libs(x86-64) >= 5.7.9 for package: mysql-community-client-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-client-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-client-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
---> Package mysql-community-common.x86_64 0:5.7.19-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:5.7.19-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsasl2.so.3()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
---> Package numactl.x86_64 0:2.0.9-2.el6 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-community-client.x86_64 0:5.7.19-1.el7 will be obsoleting
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-client-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-client-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
---> Package mysql-community-libs.x86_64 0:5.7.19-1.el7 will be obsoleting
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-libs-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
---> Package mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:5.7.19-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsasl2.so.3()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
---> Package mysql-libs.x86_64 0:5.1.73-8.0.1.el6_8 will be obsoleted
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit) for package: perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) for package: perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-libs-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit)
Error: Package: perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.el6.x86_64 (@public_ol6_latest)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
           Removing: mysql-libs-5.1.73-8.0.1.el6_8.x86_64 (@public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: mysql-community-libs-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
               Not found
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.47-4.el6.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.52-1.el6_0.1.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.61-1.el6_2.1.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.66-1.el6_3.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.66-2.el6_3.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.67-1.el6_3.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.69-1.el6_4.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.71-1.el6.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.73-5.el6_6.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.73-5.el6_7.1.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.73-7.el6.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.el6.x86_64 (@public_ol6_latest)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Removing: mysql-libs-5.1.73-8.0.1.el6_8.x86_64 (@public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: mysql-community-libs-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
               Not found
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.47-4.el6.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.52-1.el6_0.1.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.61-1.el6_2.1.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.66-1.el6_3.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.66-2.el6_3.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.67-1.el6_3.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.69-1.el6_4.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.71-1.el6.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.73-5.el6_6.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.73-5.el6_7.1.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.73-7.el6.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
           Requires: libsasl2.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
           Requires: systemd
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

tried other variant

```
yum remove mysql57-community-release.noarch
yum clean all
yum install https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch.rpm
yum install mysql-community-server
```

again returned error

```
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.el6.x86_64 (@public_ol6_latest)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Removing: mysql-libs-5.1.73-8.0.1.el6_8.x86_64 (@public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: mysql-community-libs-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
               Not found
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.47-4.el6.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.52-1.el6_0.1.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.61-1.el6_2.1.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.66-1.el6_3.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.66-2.el6_3.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.67-1.el6_3.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.69-1.el6_4.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.71-1.el6.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.73-5.el6_6.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.73-5.el6_7.1.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.73-7.el6.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
           Requires: libsasl2.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
           Requires: systemd
```

Comment: What is the output of `uname -a`? Add that to your question.

Comment: I added info about OS

Comment: Do you have mysql previous version ? it looks like obsolete dependencies already  there for libstdc++.so.6 , libc.so.6, libsasl2.so.3,,,,, you have to remove them first . but careful if its prod, other apps may depend on that obsolete dependencies

Comment: el7 but you are using el6.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the kernel version you have posted, it seems you are running Oracle Linux 6 and you should download the *Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 / Oracle Linux 6* version instead of version 7 as you tried now.

So, the following commands should work for you.

```
yum remove mysql57-community-release.noarch
yum clean all
yum install https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch.rpm
yum install mysql-community-server
```

Comment: tried your variant and result added to question

Comment: Sorry, forgot to clean up the yum cache. Edited the answer. You can just try to `yum clean all`, then `yum install mysql-community-server`. Just tested in a VM with Centos6.

Comment: tryied else time and again returned error

Comment: Unfortunately, Oracle mysql 57 did not install to Oracle Linux 6.9, case mysql 57 requires version lib glibc.x86_64 = 2.17, in Oracle Linux 6.9 only 2.12

Comment: There is still something wrong with your repositories or the `yum` cache. As you can see from the second output above, `yum` still tries to install `mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:5.7.19-1.el7` which is for REHL7/CentOS7 based systems. Therefore the wrong `libc` version is pulled in. Remove any `mysql` package that might have been installed. Check your repositories again in `/etc/yum.repos.d/` and remove anything that is related to RHEL7/CentOS7. Do a `yum clean all` again.